# Send JSON object to Hapijs Route

Tags: json, node.js, routes, hapi.js, joi

I have a method that gets query results from the database and sends one of the results as a parameter in the URL to one of my routes in Hapi.js. Is there anyway I can send a JSON object to my route?

**Route**

```
    {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/Account/{Tag}',
        config: {
            validate: {
                query: {
                    tag: Joi.string()
                }
            }
        },
    handler: function(request, reply) {
            var tag = encodeURIComponent(request.params.Tag);
            reply.view('Account/index', {tag: tag});
    }
  }
```

**Method/Query**

```
/**
   * Check if Account exists in database, then login
   * @param {String} request.query.email
   * @param {String} request.query.password
   */
  login: function(request, reply) {
    connection.query('SELECT email AS email, tag AS tag FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', [request.query.email, sha256(request.query.password)], function(error, results, fields) {
      if (results[0]) {
        //reply.(results[0]).created('/Account/' + results[0].tag);
        reply.redirect('/Account/' + results[0].tag);
      } else {
        reply.redirect('/Error');
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to my issue. I request the information I need using another query in MySQL, the store my routes reply inside the query's callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if understand your question correctly, but probably you can do this, just extending a `pre-handler` extension point to resolve this case.

If you use `pre-handler`, you can simply query and store in a request property the information you'll need.

http://hapijs.com/api#request-lifecycle